# Solaris 10 : Remove trailing blank lines from multiple files

Tags: files, solaris

I'm working on Solaris 10.What is the easiest way to remove blank lines from multiple files at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick little script should work. I got [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-command-remove-all-blank-lines/) from nixCraft a while a go and it works quite well.

```
#!/bin/sh
files="/home/me/data/*.txt"
for i in $files
do
  sed '/^$/d' $i > $i.out
  mv  $i.out $i
done
```

Replace `$files` for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be easiest to remove all blank lines:

```
sed -i.bak '/^$/d' $FILES
```

This will create a backup with the extension `.bak`, take that out if you don't want a backup.

If you want to remove lines with whitespace (and only whitespace) too, add `\W*`:

```
sed -i.bak '/^\W*$/d' $FILES
```

And this works with the `--posix` option in gnu sed (turns off gnu extensions, so I think this should work on solaris):

```
sed -i.bak '/^[ \t]*$/d' $FILES
```

Add more whitespace characters if necessary.

Comment: That would've been perfect if I had GNU sed available. I should've mention that. I'm editing my question.

Comment: I've added a line; if that one doesn't work, then which part doesn't work/behave the same?

Comment: The `-i` option is unfortunately not available. I just got home and tried it, and it worked as expected on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to only remove trailing empty lines:

```
printf %s\\n "$(cat file)"|sponge file
tac file|awk /./,0|tac|sponge file
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/\n*$/\n/' file
gsed -i ':1;/^\n*$/{$d;N;b1}' file
bsdsed -i '' -e :1 -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;b1' -e '}' file
```

Command substitutions remove all trailing linefeeds, so for example `echo "$(printf 'a\n\n')b"` prints `ab`.

`sponge` is from moreutils.

Replace `tac` with `tail -r` in BSD.

`perl -0777` sets `$_` to the whole input and `-p` prints `$_` after each line. See `man perlrun`.

`:` sets a label, `b` branches to a label, `$d` deletes the pattern space on the last line, and `N` appends the next line to the pattern space.

GNU `sed` allows semicolons after `:` and `b` but POSIX and BSD `sed` don't. `-i` works with GNU `sed` but not BSD `sed` and `-i ''` works with BSD `sed` but not GNU `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following single line command to remove blank lines across multiple files

```
find directoryname -name "filename" -print | xargs sed -i '/^$/d'
```

If for example you want to remove the blank lines from all the files found within the current directory and its sub-directories, you can use the following command:

```
find . -name "*.*" -print | xargs sed -i '/^$/d'
```